# Java - Random Image maker / embed printer

Tags: java, image, discord

So I have an EmbedBuilder (part of discord api / library for java) and I'm trying to create an image that would contain 8 smaller random images

these images would randomly selected from a file within the project. say resourced/images/.

I just don't know what function would allow me to take those images and combine them / resize them in anyway that I need.

[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziQkc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that copies one image into another by going one coordinate at a time and copying RGB over to a new file. It shouldn't be any problem for you to adjust the code to copy several images into one bigger image by adjusting coordinates

```
public static void copyImage(int height, int width) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    BufferedImage imageToCopy = ImageIO.read(new File("imageToCopy.png"));
    for (int i = 0; i < imageToCopy.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < imageToCopy.getHeight(); j++) {
            int rgb = imageToCopy.getRGB(i, j);
            bufferedImage.setRGB(i, j, rgb);
        }
    }
    File resultFile = new File("resultImage.png");
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", resultFile);
}
```